# Library class Project

Tags: java, strings, array

I am creating a class project which involves two classes: Library and Book. I would like a general review on the code.

```
public class Book
{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String summary;

    public Book() {
        title = "";
        author = "";
        summary = "";
    }

    public Book(String title, String author, String summary) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.summary = summary;
    }    

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }    

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
}

import java.util.*;
```

Next is my Library class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Library
    {        
        private String location;
        private String openingHours;
        private Book book;
        private Map<Book,Integer> bookList = new HashMap<Book,Integer>();

        public Library(String location, String openingHours) {
            this.location = location;
            this.openingHours = openingHours;
        }

        public void addBook(Book book) {        
            //If the book doesn't exist add it: otherwise increase the quantity of the book
            if (bookList.containsKey(book)) 
                bookList.put(book, bookList.get(book) + 1);
            else
                bookList.put(book, 1);
        }

        public String printOpeningHours() {
            return openingHours;
        }

        public String printAddress() {
            return location;
        }

        public void borrowBook(Book book) {
            bookList.put(book, bookList.get(book) - 1);            
        }

        public void returnBook() {
            bookList.put(book, bookList.get(book) + 1);
        }

        public String printAvailableBooks() {
            ArrayList <String> available = new ArrayList();

            for (Book books: bookList.keySet())
                available.add(books.toString());

            return available.toString();
        }

        public boolean isBorrowed() {
            int value = 0; 

            for (Book bq: bookList.keySet()) {
                value = bookList.get(bq);
                if (value > 0)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Library l1 = new Library("111 Your Street", "9am");
            l1.addBook(new Book("Test", "Author", "Test summary"));
            l1.addBook(new Book("Test2", "Author2", "Test summary2"));
            l1.addBook(new Book("Test3", "Author3", "Test summary3"));
            System.out.println(l1.printAvailableBooks());
            System.out.print("Choose book: ");
            Book book = (Book) input.next();
            borrowBook(book);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Book` class does not implement `toString()` that is why you had that output. The `toString()` method of `ArrayList` call `toString()` on each element of the iterator. Since `Book` does not override `toString()` the `Object.toString()` is used and that method only print some information read : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>         public boolean isBorrowed() {
>             int value = 0; 
>
>             for (Book bq: bookList.keySet()) {
>                 value = bookList.get(bq);
>                 if (value > 0)
>                     return true;
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
> ```

This is more complicated than needed.  You could just say

```
        public boolean hasAvailability() {
            for (int quantity: bookQuantities.values()) {
                if (quantity > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

By switching from `keySet()` to `values()` we can avoid dereferencing to get the quantity.  We just get them directly.

I changed names from `isBorrowed`, `value`, and `bookList` to be clearer about what they held.  I don't know that `hasAvailability` is correct either, but `isBorrowed` is backwards from its use in `borrowBook`.  There you decrease quantity when borrowed, here you say that it is borrowed if there is a positive quantity.

> ```
>         public String printAvailableBooks() {
>             ArrayList <String> available = new ArrayList();
> ```

As a general rule, you should give variables interface types rather than implementation.

```
            List<String> available = new ArrayList<>();
```

This allows you to switch implementations easily, in just one place.

Note that adding the `<>` should get rid of a compiler warning in Java 8.  In older versions, it would need to be `<String>`.

> ```
>             for (Book books: bookList.keySet())
>                 available.add(books.toString());
> ```

Given that you call this method `printAvailableBooks`, it would make more sense for this to `print`.

```
            for (Book book: bookQuantities.keySet()) {
                System.out.print(book.toString() + " ");
            }
```

Then it wouldn't matter that [the `toString` of `ArrayList` doesn't work the way that you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929145/i-am-getting-the-memory-address-from-an-arraylist-need-info).

```
        public String getBooksString() {
            if (bookList.isEmpty()) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder available = new StringBuilder();

            for (Book book: bookQuantities.keySet()) {
                available.append(" " + book.toString());
            }

            return available.substring(1);
        }
```

Another alternative would be to use a `StringBuilder` rather than an `ArrayList`, since you want something more like that `toString` behavior.  It uses `substring` instead of `toString` to get rid of the extra space at the beginning.

> ```
>             //If the book doesn't exist add it: otherwise increase the quantity of the book
> ```

This doesn't match the code, which checks if the book does exist and then increases the quantity if so.  The `else` or otherwise clause adds a new entry.  As written, the comment makes the code less readable.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot. I appreciate the time you have taken to review my code!!

Answer (score 3):

## Empty Constructor

Is a book with no name, author, or title a book? You should not include empty, overloaded constructors unless you know valid defaults. Empty strings are not valid defaults for titles/authors/descriptions.

## Data Types

You could use a Time type for opening hours and an Address type for location. This increases code readability, clarity of your api, and type safety...

```
private Address location;
private Time openingHours;
```

## Method Names

Your library print functions don't print anything, but rather return values! If you have a method `printAddress()`, I would suspect that the address is printed to the console. Instead, it would make more sense to call this method `getAddress()`.

These are a few quick things I noticed. I'll try to complete this answer later.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comments. I will fix as recommended.